# Shared Storage & Oracle Clusterware

Tags: oracle, cluster-computing

Need to ask a basic question regarding the shared storage mechanism in the RAC environment. I have been through documentations but need someone to confirm the following:

In my scenario, the database is Oracle 11g on Windows 2008 R2. The question is that how will all the nodes participating in the Cluster be connected to the shared storage? Is it through LAN or is it possible to have physical storage in one of the nodes participating in the cluster while other nodes are connected to that node via LAN? The simple question is that where will this shared storage reside?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The storage will need to be visible to all the nodes, this can be done in various ways. If you are starting on rac its probably a good idea to look through some of the tutorials at [oracle-base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-db-10gr2-rac-installation-on-linux-using-nfs.php)